# Django form field queryset optimization

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form like this on Django app:

```
class CustomForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ModelA.objects.filter(type=A))
    field2 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ModelA.objects.filter(type=B))
```

The Debug Toolbar tells me there are two duplicates querys on **ModelA** but the filter conditions it's different. Is this a bug?. Also I was wondering if there is a way to optimize this case and make only one query

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModelA.objects.filter(type=A)` and `ModelA.objects.filter(type=B)` are two separate querysets, so require two queries.

In theory, you could do

```
ModelA.objects.filter(type__in=[A, B])
```

Which would get all objects where `type=A` or `type=B`. You could then filter the list in Python. However, this wouldn't necessarily perform any better. You wouldn't be able to use the `ModelChoiceField` any more, so your code would be more complicated.